# How to scrape the webapp clock value using Selenium and Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, python-3.10

I am trying to use a webapp clock vs. my system clock to trigger events. I want to scrape the value of the webapp clock (serverClock).

The source code for the page contains:

```
<p class="server_time">
<span class="serverTime">Today's date is: <b>Thursday&nbsp;12/15/2022</b></span>
<span class="serverClock"><span>The Server Time is: <b class="jquery_server_clock" data- 
ftclub="canyonoakscc"></b></span>
</p>
```

Comment: OK, what is the problem to do so?

Comment: Maybe I am little bit lost, but I do not see any value for `serverClock` element. I see value `Thursday&nbsp;12/15/2022` for `serverTime` but I do not see any value for `serverClock`, I only see `The Server Time is:` but I guess that is not the text you want, isn't it?

Comment: I ran the code using the css_selector but the value returned was "None"

Comment: Same result using XPATH  "None"

Comment: I believe I'm looking for the value of  "jquery_server_clock"

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the webapp clock (serverClock) you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.server_time span.serverClock > span b").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='server_time']//span[@class='serverClock']/span//b").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

Comment: I ran the code using the css_selector but the value returned was "None"

Comment: I'm expecting a time value in the 12:15:03 format

Comment: @Searcher512 Apologies for the late reply but the relevant HTML is missing a `</span>` and is malformed atm.